What else should I do to address a mystery leak?
About two years ago I noticed one of my showers was leaking. I didn't have the wherewithal to fix it at the time so l just shut down the shower. I opened up the ceiling recently to finally deal with this project, called a plumber in... and it's not leaking anymore. Pipe looks fine. There are some old wet spots from these photos. I ran the shower awhile, nothing. Threw buckets of water at the shower walls, got my jeans soaked but no leaks.
Plumber says maybe just a caulk/grout issue on the sides that only comes up occasionally. I was planning to close the ceiling while leaving an access panel in case I need to go back in and continue to monitor it. But curious, based on this story and the photos, if there's something else I can do to check for leak source before I put drywall back.



There look like water stains in the blue circled areas:

Maybe the tile floor or where the floor drain joins the tile floor is leaking?

That was my assumption — a pan problem, or the pipe isn’t securely attached to the pan.
Do you think this is a solution with caulk and grout, or am I potentially going to have to replace my shower floor (and thus my whole shower)?

I regret that tile & showers are rather far outside my skillset. Will have to let the house builders weigh in.

I would continue to monitor.  Perhaps you can tape up some toilet paper in the locations @Triplefault pointed out (plus the trap drain)—this will help tell you whether leaks are continuing.

There is some corrosion and oxidation on the trap plug so that might have been the leak and the rust/corrosion could loosen up in time. It's a great idea to install the access panel to continue to monitor this.  I'd use the shower for awhile before adding drywall since leaks never happen the way we plan them.
